# How to synchronise data in local MySQL database with Cloud SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a Django application which is deployed on GAE. I have the same models on the prod server and the dev server. However, the content on both databases are different.

Actually, I'd like to do some tests on that data without screwing with the actual data on the cloud. Is there any way that I can pull the data in my Cloud SQL to my local MySQL db?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can start fresh in development (empty tables), you could have auto_increments with primary key in development, and foreign key constraints there.

Perform

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/full/path/to/fileParentXXX.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM ParentXXX;
```

(same concept for other tables). Grab those exported CSV (comma-separated value) text files, bringing them back over the wire to development server.

Perform `LOAD DATA INFILE` on development with Parents **first**, then Children tables that have Foreign Key constraints depending on those FK's. The auto_incs should remain happy in development.

Mysql Manual page for load data link is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).